# How much time do I have to spend in hell to earn the "Medium Well" achievement in Super Meat Boy?

Tags: achievements, super-meat-boy

So, during the Steam Summer Sale 2011, Super Meat Boy was updated and has a new achievement: "Medium Well". It's description is only, "Spend as little time in hell as possible"

How do I earn this new achievement?

Unless I messed up with my calculator, the A+'s for each level in hell put you at a time total of 631.8 seconds.

**Update:** Super Meat Boy was later updated in 2011-07-20 and what was originally the "Medium Rare" achievement has now been renamed to ["Medium Well"](http://store.steampowered.com/news/5871/).

Comment: I just A+ all the normal hell levels (not the dark ones) including the boss and didnt get it yet

Comment: Wow, you really hit the Google jackpot. 3k views already! Understandable, though. Damn cryptic objectives.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26446/what-are-the-secret-achievements-in-super-meat-boy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SMB team has said on Twitter that it counts a sum of the best play times in Hell.

From the [Super Meat Boy Forums](http://supermeatboy.com/forum/index.php/topic,2013.new.html):

> You must clear Hell, both light and dark world
>
> The sum of your best times in Hell must be less than some threshold

[Apparently](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1261009#1261009), the threshold is 500 seconds.

Comment: I'm under 500 now, but I can't seem to get the achievement - I checked, and the achievement isn't showing up with the rest of them on the steam stats page. Anyway I can force the game to check for updates?

Comment: Okay, weird. It showed up a couple hours after I got < 500. It showed up as soon as I got to the main menu, so don't know what delayed it.

Comment: The threshold seems to be exactly 500 (I got it with 499.43), you must restart the game and go back to the main menu to unlock it, and full A+ and the boss are *not* required (I don't have an A+ on 4-20X)