# In Killing Floor, how do I earn the "The Big Hunt" achievement?

Tags: achievements, killing-floor

While I own Killing Floor due to the Potato Sack earlier this year, it is one of the games in my steam library that has seen little use (TF2 being my go-to multiplayer FPS).

As such, while the "The Big Hunt" achievement isn't flagrantly ambiguous (like some *other* [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/25660/336)) I still haven't the faintest clue as to how to achieve it.

> **Killing Floor**
>
> The Big Hunt - Kill a circus Scrake with a crossbow

Where can I acquire a crossbow (I assume from the in-game merchant?), and where can I encounter a circus Scrake? (For that matter, what *is* a circus Scrake?) Is there a particular level best suited to obtaining this achievement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scrakes are the enemies that chase you around with a chainsaw.

I haven't had a chance to play Killing Floor yet since the update, but if it's anything like the Christmas update, Circus Scrakes have replaced regular Scrakes in every level.

According to the KF Wiki:

> For the Summer Sideshow he was reskinned into "the Incredible man monkey", a giant cymbal monkey, this time retaining the chainsaw arm.

I believe they start appearing in the fifth wave during a Long game, third during a Medium game.

The Crossbow is sold by the in-game vendor for £800.

Comment: Thanks, it was easy enough to solo. Clown Patriarch killed me pretty dead, though. (And it may have been the 4th wave on medium, not the 3rd)